# React.cloneElement: add css class to children

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Inside a basic vite/js/react/mui project I have this simple structure:

```
//example1 - does not work
<DemoContainer>
  <DemoChild />
  <DemoChild />
</DemoContainer>
```

I want to add a css class to all elements passed into `DemoContainer` via cloneElement:

```
export function DemoContainer({ children }) {
  const redKids = React.Children.map(children, (child) => React.cloneElement(child, {className: "some-class" }));

  return (
    <div>
    {redKids}
    </div>
  );
}

export function DemoChild() {
  return <div/>;
}

// and the content of 'some-class':
.some-class {
  background-color: red;
}
```

---

**I would expect all `DemoChild` elements to have `some-class` attached to them but that is not the case. `class="some-class"` is nowhere to be seen in the dom...**

Interestingly it works fine with simple divs as children:

```
//example2 - works fine
<DemoContainer>
  <div/>
  <div/>
  <div/>
</DemoContainer>
```

---

What is going on here? Why does it work on `div` but not on `DemoChild`?
What am I missing?

I made a small demo if you would like to play with the problem:
[Click](https://codesandbox.io/embed/boring-wood-sq9s8y?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

The blue outlined boxes are DemoChild elements (which should be filled red) and the green outlined boxes are simple divs.

Thanks in advance!

---

PS: I know there are alternative ways to pass styles/classes to children, but please lets focus only on the cloneElement approach I sketched above.

Comment: You didn't set the `className` prop on the `div` in `DemoChild`.

Comment: @Wing Care to elaborate? I obviously don't see the problem after staring at it for too long...

Comment: In `DemoChild` you need to set the `className` on the `div`, getting it from the component props. For example: `function DemoChild({ className }) { return (<div className={className} ... >...</div>); }`.

Comment: Is that really necessary? Why does it work in the second example on the simple divs ?

Comment: I'll write out an answer. I was considering to close as a typo but that's a good question.

Comment: I've written out an answer. Hopefully it makes sense, let me know in the comments if you have more questions :)

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

`React.cloneElement`'s first two parameters are:

1. The element to be cloned
2. The props to apply to the element

When the `element` parameter is a `div` and the `props` parameter is `{ className: "some-class" }` the *output* is:

```
<div className="some-class"></div>
```

As the above is a DOM element, that's what it'll look like in the DOM (with `className` translated to `class`).

When the `element` parameter is `DemoChild` and the `props` parameter is `{ className: "some-class" }` the *output* is:

```
<DemoChild className="some-class" />
```

However, the above *output* isn't actually what the eventual DOM looks like. It'll be whatever your component returns. As your original component definition (below) doesn't set the `className` on the `div`, the `div` doesn't get a `className`.

```
function DemoChild() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        height: "50px",
        outline: "2px solid blue",
        marginBottom: "10px"
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Props on a component aren't spread onto the element returned by the component. Imagine you had a more complex component that takes in more props and all the props were spread onto the element it returned – the DOM would be a mess.

## Solution

You need to ensure the element returned by your component has its `className` set from its prop:

```
function DemoChild({ className }) {
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      style={{
        height: "50px",
        outline: "2px solid blue",
        marginBottom: "10px"
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Full demo below:

```js
const { StrictMode } = React;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;

function DemoContainer({ children }) {
  const redKids = React.Children.map(children, (child) =>
    React.cloneElement(child, { className: "some-class" })
  );

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: "300px",
        height: "300px",
        padding: "5px",
        outline: "2px solid black"
      }}
    >
      {redKids}
    </div>
  );
}

function DemoChild({ className }) {
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      style={{
        height: "50px",
        outline: "2px solid blue",
        marginBottom: "10px"
      }}
    />
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DemoContainer>
        <DemoChild />
        <DemoChild />
        <div
          style={{
            height: "50px",
            outline: "2px solid green",
            marginBottom: "10px"
          }}
        />
        <div
          style={{
            height: "50px",
            outline: "2px solid green",
            marginBottom: "10px"
          }}
        />
      </DemoContainer>
    </div>
  );
}


const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<StrictMode><App /></StrictMode>);
```

```css
.some-class {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I really (!) appreciate your effort! But your conclusion why it works on a div but fails on DemoChild does not convince me. When logging children inside DemoContainer, the only difference is in type ( 'div' vs 'fDemoChild()' ) which may suggests that components and 'native' DOM elements are handled differently by cloneElement. 

I will give this here a couple more days and eventually ask again in directly in reacts github...

Comment: @cl10k: Why do you think the difference in type means they're handled differently? Surely because they're different types, it means they're handled the samed as different things were passed into `cloneElement`. If `DemoChild` turned into a `div` I would suspect things were handled differently because `cloneElement` turned my component into a `div`. But in our case it has not.

Comment: @cl10k: the log is further evidence of what I described in my answer. `f DemoChild()` is a function (component) called `DemoChild` – the JSX representation would be `<DemoChild />`. If you look in the object there'll be another key named `props` which will have `className: "some-class"` in it. This is what I essentially described in my answer. Granted my answer simplifies things (hence the italicised "output") because going into how React renders things will be too long.

Comment: @cl10k: here's the link to `cloneElement`'s source: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/cb3404a0ccd8b5edf5d2b90bd844742090e38f42/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L486-L558 for your own perusal.

Comment: I get your argumentation! My interest in the technical reasoning is just not (yet) satisfied. I'll have a look at the cloneElement source later today...

Comment: @cl10k: one thing you might be misunderstanding is a component that returns a `div` is not the same as a `div` by itself. In other words `<div /> !== <DemoChild />`.  In the DOM it may look the same but to React they are not. You can see this by installing [React Dev Tools](https://react.dev/learn/react-developer-tools) and inspecting your [Code Sandbox demo](https://sq9s8y.csb.app/). You may need to go into **Settings** and disable "Hide components where... `type` _equals_ `dom nodes`". In the component tree, `DemoChild` is a sibling of `div`s and `DemoChild` has `div`s inside of them.

Comment: @cl10k: I just had an additional thought: you're thinking `cloneElement` handles DOM elements and React components differently because you might be thinking the DOM element and React component are equivalent yet the output is different. However this needs to be reframed. The different outputs are not because `cloneElement` handles DOM elements and React components differently but because the DOM element and React component are not equivalent in the first place.

Comment: @cl10k: all of the above is just my reading from your question and the comments. I could be trying to read too much. Happy to take feedback :)

Comment: Again, I very much appreciate your help! I need to get my regular work done first, before I can (re)focus on this topic.

About the differences of native DOM elements and React components: I don't think that <div/> is handled like a html div. The compiler is already interpreting it as a react component. You can clearly see that when logging {children}. The only difference seems to be the type property. I suspect that "primitives" might be handled differently by react, but that should be easy to find out with the source to cloneElement you provided.